# Is modding Xbox 360 games difficult or dangerous to the game/system/saved files?

Tags: xbox-360, mods

I'm a huge fan of visual mods but I often only see mods done by PC gamers and not console gamers.

I've heard that in order to mod a console game all you need to do is download the mod onto a USB and stick that into your console. Is it really that easy?

I ask if it is difficult because i've never seen Xbox gamers use visual mods that make the game look cool/more interesting. I've only seen players mod or hack the game for online purposes.

Which brings me to my next question,

If modding isn't (or even if it is) difficult to do on an Xbox 360 can it be dangerous to the game or the system itself?

Comment: You can take a look at Modio a windows software that allows Xbox 360 save editing.

Answer (score 6):

It is impossible to mod Xbox 360 (or more general, any console) games without jailbreaking it to allow unsigned content to run.

Besides that, games on PC have the advantage of being capable of running on hardware that is better than what the game was designed for. Meaning there's extra performance available for better graphics.

Console games run on a fixed platform and are optimized to run as fast as possible on that platform. That means they often run at 30 fps, 720p compared to 60 fps 1080p that most high end PCs can run their games on.

Making the game look better takes more resources, which consoles just don't have available for a given game.