# In Minecraft how do you make a trident?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I play Minecraft on Survival all the time, I just never found out how to craft a trident. I’ve been dying to know how. Nobody will tell me. I really want to know so then I can craft one, and tell others how to. I’m just really badly wanting to know. Can you tell me?

Comment: Why you put incorrect tag even though you know?

Comment: What is the version that you are playing on and what device

Comment: In that case, [minecraft-lecacy-console] is indeed the correct tag.

Comment: You should not change the entire question after getting an answer, this is unfair to the answer authors and invalidates existing answers and comments.

Comment: Ask another question.

Comment: It won’t allow me to ask another question. This being the only reason I’ve done so.

Comment: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/566903)

Comment: Okay I’ll definitely check this out!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Trident was added to the Xbox 360 edition with the [Aquatic update](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Xbox_360_Edition_TU69), which was the last major update the edition received before being completely superseded by Bedrock Edition.

**Tridents were never craftable since their release.** In vanilla Minecraft, they can only be acquired by killing [drowned](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Drowned) that are carrying them. The drop rates for the Legacy Console Editions are hard to come by, but there's currently a 15% chance in Bedrock Edition (6.25% in Java Edition) a drowned will spawn with a trident. A *drowned carrying a trident* has an 8.5% chance to drop it on death. This means that in Bedrock Edition, a trident *should* drop every 78 (188 in Java Edition) drowned kills on average. These numbers are based on statistics and are not guaranteed. I expect the Legacy Console Edition numbers to be similar.

Since then, the addition of a trident crafting recipe has been a [fairly requested feature](https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/search?query=trident%20crafting) and plenty of community-made mods and Data Packs have implemented it, but I'm afraid none of these apply to Legacy Console Editions, as modding console games [is no easy feat](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/236311).

Comment: @DevilsbestfriendisLunar If this answer helped you please click the check button on this answer to mark the problem solved.

Comment: Since the question does appear indeed to be about the legacy console edition, can you include some information about that edition in your answer as well?

Comment: @Unionhawk did my best to include more information, although I was unable to find any information on the exact spawn/drop rates for that edition. If anyone happens to come across a source, I'd be happy to include it in the answer.

Comment: I didn’t add any info on my edition in my question. I really don’t know much about editions.

Comment: @DevilsbestfriendisLunar In a nutshell: minecraft legacy console is for consoles. Like XBOX. It has been deprecated. Java is for computer. That means playing will be a more comfortable expirience and you can play with commands in creative ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sv6LuPmMGcY&list=WL&index=41)). Bedrock means mobile and other low-end devices, like Nintendo Switch (you heard that right). These versions do vary in functionality and other things though. Understood?

Comment: That makes so much more sense! Though, what does vanilla mean?

Comment: @DevilsbestfriendisLunar "vanilla" means "the base game", or "no additional flavors" - **in Minecraft that means "no mods"**. In some other games it can also mean "no DLCs" (like in World of Warcraft). Also I'd like to clarify Bedrock Edition also means PCs, newer consoles (Xbox One and further), mobile and other devices. It's a version of minecraft that runs everywhere and is slightly different than the Java Edition, which only exists on PCs. Java and Bedrock exist side-by-side.

Comment: Okay. So then would that mean I play vanilla legacy console edition?

Comment: @DevilsbestfriendisLunar Yup! The Bedrock Edition was never made available to Xbox 360 - so you must be playing the Legacy Console Edition (LCE). And the LCE is [nearly impossible to mod](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/237115), so you're most definitely playing vanilla :)

Comment: Okay. That makes a lot more sense now!